# How can I save the learning progress when training the neural network in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

My intention is to use the MLPRegressor to on (x,y) tuples dataset to estimate y = f(x). The goal is to save the neural netwok after each epoch during the learning. I'd like to make an animation showing how the network is getting better during the learning process.

Is there a way how to do that without tinkering with the source code? When I was doing similar task on different occassions (f.e. optimization) I simply used the *callback* option which is not available here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
from sklearn import neural_network
m = neural_network.MLPRegressor()
# define data X, y

for j in m.max_iter:
    
    m.partial_fit(X=x, y=y) # or m.fit(X=x, y=y, incremental=True)           
    # <your code after each training increment>
```

`partial_fit` appears to be designed for this case. The docs read: "Update the model with a single iteration over the given data."  Early stopping might cause an error or warning but should be easy to handle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me.

Comment: if you want a "nicer" solution, you could subclass the model and add a callback function to the `fit` method